# Extract High-level CFG Structure from LLVM-IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

One of my current projects needs to convert some sample LLVM IR back to C code without using goto statements and too many redundant variables. I know that converting LLVM back to C is not recommended but that is the fastest way in my project given the time budget.

A LLVM C-backend like https://github.com/JuliaComputing/llvm-cbe typically generates a c code with many goto statements. So I'm wondering if that is because the CFG in LLVM is not that structured, meaning the back-end does not know when the selection (if-else) get merged.

I found a pass called StructurizeCFG that brings a lot of bool variables and phi nodes, which might not be the best option for me.

So my question is that is there any ways to extract high-level CFG (loop-merge, selection-merge, etc.) from LLVM-IR?

Comment: LoopInfo might help you. But this is really too broad for SO.

Comment: Loopinfo can help for sure, I'm curious on how to find selection merge (if-else etc) points.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I used llvm-spirv + spirv-cross to recover C code. Utilizing loopinfo I inserted loopmerge in llvm-spirv. Selection is now a question mark to me as there's no metadata. Thinking about how domination analysis can come into play.

Comment: Well, a then/else pair is two sets of blocks that share both dominator and postdominator. Switch is the same, except with n sets instead of two, so iterating over the nodes ina DominatorTree and checking each node against a PostDominatorTree should get you there. There are quite a few t's to cross and i's to dot.

Comment: Tricky thing is if inside if/else blocks there is a return instruction, domination analysis may not help. Those blocks' ipdom become root(program end), then the structure is messed up.

Comment: Yes. As I said, t's to cross and i's to dot.